# Protocol for sending streaming data over multiple sockets

Tags: sockets, streaming, bigdata, network-protocols

I am working on designing an API for consuming messages from an application that will generate a very large amount of data; 10+ of GB/s is likely, even for smaller clients.  I am looking for a protocol that allows me to deliver this data in a way that is easy for clients to consume.

The obvious answer for me is: split up the messages so they are consumable over multiple connections. Each connection would consume a fraction of the overall load.

But if I do this, there are a few things I need to account for:

- How does the user know they are falling behind and need to launch more connections?

  - Twitter says [consumers should check timestamps](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/processing), which could work for us
- When they launch a new connection to consume more of the data, how do they specify that this is part of the same consumption session?

  - We could give the session a name, correlate that with a ["direct" amqp queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html), and let our queue do the hard work
- Is there something very important I am missing.

  - Probably.

For this reason, I'd much rather a protocol that already exists.

The protocol would be considered **extra awesome** if it:

- is websocket or streaming HTTP friendly
- supports data compression

Answer (score 1):

The problems you are describing are pretty much the same issues that video streaming has to deal with, which you probably already know. The key HTTP friendly streaming protocols are HLS (Apple), SmoothStreaming (Microsoft), HDS (Adobe) and MPEG-DASH (open protocol, but new).

When considering video streaming, it is also worth understanding whether your streams are more like 'live' streams or 'static' content - the former is generated on the fly and any given part of the live stream may only be available for a set tine, while the latter stored on the server in full and generally any part is available at any time (until the content is removed). How you stream and playback these is subtly different.

It may be that you can simply reuse one of the above video streaming protocols by wrapping your data as if it were video (or maybe it even is video), and implementing your own custom client on the receiving side.

Alternatively, these protocols could provide a good reference point if you wanted to create your own simpler protocol - there are several open source streaming servers you could look to for ideas or even adapt to your needs if that looks like a sensible route:

- http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org
- http://icecast.org

Video streaming is quite complex as you may already be aware, but if your use cases are simpler you may be able to ignore or remove much of the complexity - for example you may not need seek, multiple format and bit rate streams, accompanying streams (for subtitles etc). Being able to simplify like this might justify the effort to modify one of the above for your needs, if you are not able to use them out of the box.

One final point - video and audio streaming protocols usually have a built in way of dealing with delayed or lost packets. Depending on your application these may not be applicable to you so you should look carefully at this aspect if reusing a video or audio streaming protocol or server. For example, audio clients are typically tolerant of a small amount of packet loss, and will generally discard delayed packets rather than pause the audio (packets received outside the 'jitter buffer' window). If your application cannot tolerate any packet loss, then you will need to look carefully at the underlying solution and protocol to make sure it really meets your needs over all network conditions.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I was originally searching for solutions the streaming video protocols kept popping up. For our particular solution, accuracy in the data stream is pretty important (more important than absolute performance), so the more lossy protocols may not be the best match.  Still, there are some ideas in these we should be able to borrow from.